# How to change print params when using new java 1.6 JTextComponent print()

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtextcomponent

I have a JTextComponent (JTextArea). I am trying to print its contents with using the new 1.6 .print() functionality. This is working well. I am also doing this in a headless/non-interactive mode using the following method signature:

`boolean print(MessageFormat headerFormat, MessageFormat footerFormat, boolean showPrintDialog, PrintService service, PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes, boolean interactive);`

Again this prints out my content.

HOWEVER... I would like to set my own print parameters (namely Margin size and Paper Size)..Mine are custom/non-standard as this is for a receipt printer -

Is there any way to set/configure this information when using this form of printing ?

The problem I am having now is trying to get my content to fit the printable area - and I would love to have more control - I guess using PrintJob and Document this would be available through the PageFormat object - But I don't know how to do same using the convience print method above.

Thanks in advance
-A-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes to specify the attributes of the print job.

You create a new instance of the `PrintRequestAttributeSet`

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
```

You then need to add the attributes for your request to that set. [Take a look here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/Attribute.html) for all the different attributes that you can use.

I think you will need [MediaSize](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/MediaSize.html) and [MediaPrintableArea](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/MediaPrintableArea.html)

Comment: Again - I want to use a custom MediaSize - not one of the standard ones. I assumed it might be as straightforward as above. However when I call the following: attributes.add(new MediaSize(80, 3000, Size2DSyntax.MM)); I get a class cast exception from internal verifyAttributeValue... which seems strange

Comment: Actually that was my problem - I was concentrating on MediaSize. I just tried a custom MediaPrintableArea and it looks much better!

Comment: can you please commit you working code? i have the same problem.